# Doubts on moving RDS instance from EC2-Classic to VPC

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I need to move RDS oracle instance from EC2-Classic to a VPC, i have some important questions not found on AWS docs:

- Is there any downtime ? If so, how much?
- The database endpoint will change after the migration?
- EC2-VPC instances could still using the db endpoint transparently?

If anyone already did this migration i would like to hear the overall experience.

Thanks!

Comment: The answers to these questions depend on how you've set up your database. If you're using a tool such as GoldenGate, you should be able to set up an in-VPC replica and minimize downtime. Otherwise you'll have to restore from a snapshot. In any case, your clients will have some level of interruption because the physical instance will have changed (so even if the endpoint name doesn't change you'll need to reconnect).

Comment: That said, this isn't a programming question, so is off topic for this site. You should repost, _with a complete description of your current deployment_ on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thanks @kdgregory in my case im using Oracle and i think read-replica is not available. Anyway i will move the question to server fault.